# Toggling multiple element clases with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created multiple form input fields that will feature a hidden pop up when the use click on the input field.

**[Fiddle HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/natedoesntknow/jn1pbnqs/10/)**

**How it works :**

When the user click on input field one the class `is-displayed` is added the div parent `protect-field-container`. When the user clicks on input field two the class `is-displayed` is removed from element one and is added to element two.

I can't seem to get this function to work the way i want it to work. Below is a snippet of my code.

**Jquery :**

```
$('.popUp-block').on("click", function(){
    var $popUp = $(this).closest('.protect-field-container')

    if ($popUp.hasClass('is-displayed')) {
       $popUp.toggleClass('is-displayed');
    } else {
        $popUp.addClass('is-displayed');
    }
});
```

**HTML :**

```
<div class="field-container">
    <div class="protect-field-container two-cols col-md-4">

        <article class="protect-field planner-form">
            <label for="#">Who shall we think about ? <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></label>
            <input type="text" class="characters popUp-block">
            <i class="valid-checked fa fa-check-circle"></i>
            <i class="invalid-checked fa fa-times-circle"></i>
        </article>

        <div class="protect-popup">
            <h3>Permanent Total and Partial Disability</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.</p>
            <a href="#">More information</a>
            <span>&euro; 100,000 - &euro; 50,000</span>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jn1pbnqs/11/)**

You don't have to use toggle in this case, you could just remove class `is-displayed` from all the containers when the user click and add it to the current clicked field container, e.g :

```
$('.popUp-block').on("click",function() {
    //Remove class from all the containers
    $('.protect-field-container').removeClass('is-displayed');

    //Add class to the current clicked container
    $(this).closest('.protect-field-container').addClass('is-displayed');
});
```

Or you could make it just by using `show/hide` functions, check example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('.protect-popup').hide();

$('.popUp-block').on("click",function() {
  $('.protect-popup').hide();
  $(this).closest('.protect-field-container').find('.protect-popup').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field-container">
  <div class="protect-field-container two-cols col-md-4">
    <article class="protect-field planner-form">
      <label for="#">Who shall we think about ? <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></label>
      <input type="text" class="characters popUp-block">
      <i class="valid-checked fa fa-check-circle"></i>
      <i class="invalid-checked fa fa-times-circle"></i>
    </article>
    <div class="protect-popup">
      <h3>Permanent Total and Partial Disability</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.</p>
      <a href="#">More information</a>
      <span>&euro; 100,000 - &euro; 50,000</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="protect-field-container two-cols col-md-4">
    <article class="protect-field planner-form">
      <label for="#">How many childern do have ? <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></label>
      <input type="text" name="" class="characters popUp-block">
      <i class="valid-checked fa fa-check-circle"></i>
      <i class="invalid-checked fa fa-times-circle"></i>
    </article>
    <div class="protect-popup">
      <h3>Permanent Total and Partial Disability</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.</p>
      <a href="#">More information</a>
      <span>&euro; 100,000 - &euro; 50,000</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="protect-field-container two-cols col-md-4">
    <article class="protect-field planner-form">
      <label for="#">Who shall we think about ? <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></label>
      <input type="text" class="characters popUp-block">
      <i class="valid-checked fa fa-check-circle"></i>
      <i class="invalid-checked fa fa-times-circle"></i>
    </article>
    <div class="protect-popup">
      <h3>Permanent Total and Partial Disability</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.</p>
      <a href="#">More information</a>
      <span>&euro; 100,000 - &euro; 50,000</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```